# Nested navigation with params is not working in react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

i am trying to use nested routing inside my application. in this case shop page is located on **/shop** url and i want to render  **CollectionsOverview** on **/shop/** and **CollectionPage** on **/shop/:collection** and the CollectionsOverview is working fine but 
CollectionPage is not working. i even tried to use hardcoded path like /shop/abc but its still not working.. please help

**version of my react-router-dom is ^5.0.0**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route, Switch,Router} from 'react-router-dom';


function CollectionPage() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      CollectionPage
    </div>
  );
}

function CollectionsOverview() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      CollectionsOverview
    </div>
  );
}

 export default function ShopPage({match}){
return(
  <div className='shop-page'>
    <Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path={`${match.path}`} component={CollectionsOverview}/>
    <Route exact path={`${match.path}/:collectionId `} component={CollectionPage}/>
    </Switch>
    </Router>
  </div>
)
}
```

Comment: Try removing `exact` from the second route `CollectionPage`

Comment: i have tried removing both the exact.

Comment: Do u have any other `Router` and `Switch` in a higher level component, naturally `App.js` ?

Comment: Why do you have 2 `CollectionPage` functional component? I think second one must be `CollectionsOverview`.

Comment: @SultanH. yes i do have Router in App.js

Answer (score 0):

Try this, since you already have a `Router` wrapping your `App` component, you don't need another one having it's own context in the `ShopPage`, since it's -supposedly- is originally routed from `App`, in the context of the `Router` that lives in the `App`

```
export default function ShopPage({match}){
  return (
    <div className='shop-page'>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path={`${match.path}`} component={CollectionsOverview}/>
        <Route exact path={`${match.path}/:collectionId `} component={CollectionPage}/>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You'll need the `Switch` only to determine navigating decision for it's `Route` components

Comment: Do u have a reason on why using `${math.path}` instead of just `shop`.

Comment: sorry `match.path` in `path={`${match.path}/:collectionId`}}`